# Meaning of "had brought on a faint rumbly in his tumbly that Pooh knew would only get louder"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "had brought on a faint rumbly in his tumbly that Pooh knew would only get louder" in the following sentence,

> "What a pleasant surprise!" cried Kanga, welcoming them and setting
>   two more places at the table. Pooh had already had a full breakfast.
>   But it seemed the walk to Kanga and Roo's house **had brought on a faint
>   rumbly in his tumbly that Pooh knew would only get louder**.

?

Does it mean "the walk to Kanga and Roo's house had made so a faint rumbly noise in his tumbly stomach that Pooh knew the noise in the Pooh's stomach would only get louder" ?

Comment: Max// your answer and your comment helped me. your answer and your comment is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two words, "rumbly" and "tumbly", are used here with creative license. They are being used for rhyming purposes and to replicate a sort of whimsical, childish manner of speaking.

Here, "rumbly" is actually the noun "rumble", and "tumbly" is the word "tummy" (= stomach). In other words, the walk caused a faint rumble in Pooh's tummy. Your stomach rumbles when you're hungry. So we understand that Pooh became hungry after his walk. He knew this noise would get louder, which means he would become hungrier.

Comment: If so (Pooh knew would only get louder = Pooh knew the noise would only get louder), The subject (the noise) in the sentence, "Pooh knew would only get louder" is omitted. Is it a grammatically correct sentence?

Comment: Now I understand it. Before, I have misknown that "that Pooh knew would only get louder' mean not "the rumble (=that) Pooh knew would only get louder" but "that Pooh knew that the rumble would only get louder" . Now I know that "that Pooh knew would only get louder' mean not "that Pooh knew that the rumble would only get louder" but "the rumble (=that) Pooh knew would only get louder".